Local development with DefaultAzureCredential() with API Scope & App Roles
I am struggling to fully understand how to get this working, any pointers would be massively appreciated. I am trying to get my app to use local azure signed in account, and when in the app use the managed identity to get a valid token from Entra to call my API using an exposed API scope in Entra. Here's my setup:
Entra

Created an App Registration in Entra to represent my API
Created a Scope under > Expose an API:
Expose an API App Reg
Created 'App Roles' for API read access:
App Role
On the Enterprise Application, I have given the app I want to consume my app access to the App Role from step 3. This is the system managed identity SPN. I've also added my own account.
Enterprise Entra App

.NET
Using Azure.Identity; etc
...

var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var client = new HttpClient();
var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext([
    "api://MY_APP_REG_ID/API.Access",
]));

Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.Token);

var result = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.somedomain.com/v1/.....");

I was expecting this to work locally, by using az login or my Visual Studio Code Azure Signed In Account, and then when it runs in my Azure Web App, it would use the managed identity from step 4 on the Entra part.
When I run this locally, I just get:
> dotnet run
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No response received from the managed identity endpoint.
- Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json
- Please run 'az login' to set up account
- Azure PowerShell authentication failed due to an unknown error. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. 

If I run az account get-access-token --scope api://MY_APP_REG_ID/API.Access and run my code, it works. But this should not be necessary, I thought it would just use my logged in account and cycle through the different identity options nested in the DefaultAzureCredential()
If I create a client Id secret and specify that, it works too, but I want it to use a managed identity when it runs in the app service in Azure and use the developers Azure account when running locally on their machines for development.
Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Refer this MSQ&A once

Authentication first checks for EnvironmentCredentials.You need to set the credentials in local Environment Variables.

A few things that got this fixed for me: 1) I opted to installed Azure Developer CLI via winget install microsoft.azd and then used azd auth login - this worked. 2) I also added the Microsoft Azure CLI Enterprise App GUID to my App Registration 'Expose an API' - Authorized client applications to my scope. GUID "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46" which will be the same for your tenant. These two things have allowed local dev azure accounts access to the library, and will use the MI in Azure.

Even I got the same error initially with your code.

DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.

As per this MSDoc, the order of DefaultAzureCredential starts with EnvironmentCredential.

When you run the Application locally, by default it looks for the credentials in Environment Variables.

You need to set the credentials in Environment Variables.

Set the credentials to be available only for the current project from the application => Properties section.




I got the below error with API scope - API.Access.


Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: 'ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: '
MsalServiceException: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope api://****/API.Access is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI). Trace ID: **** Correlation ID: **** Timestamp:
2024-11-29 10:12:30Z 



Change the below line from API.Access to ./default as shown below.

 var accessToken = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "api://****/API.Access" });

to
var accessToken = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "api://****/.default" });

Output:


Thanks. However, the docs you linked states "Attempts to authenticate with each of these credentials, in the following order, stopping when one provides a token:". I don't want developers to have to maintain a secret locally. So it should use the local az login session, no? Also, the reason for the API.Access it that it is delegated to another app, therefore giving me API control for others who will consume the API. By changing to .default, this defeats the point of the API exposed scope

If you don't want to store them locally, you can retrieve using KeyVault.Or if you want to call any particular credentila, use VisualStudioCredential  or AzureCliCredential options.

az login session is used when you go with AzureCliCredential.

I thought AzureCliCredential was nested within the DefaultAzureCredential() which is why I thought it would work using that option. So it is not possible without adding a client secret to the app, essentially?

Strangely, it has actually worked by installing the AZD CLI tool, using my API.Access scope.

Glad it worrked..

AzureCliCredential is nested within the DefaultAzureCredentialitself, but as I mentioned it will check the order.To use AzureCliCredential directly , it is better to mention the option.
